# The coordinates for a text node in tikz specifies the centre of the box. Is there a way to get it to specify the left edge of the box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, text

I would like the two lines of text to the right of the diagonal lines to be left aligned. Is there any way to do this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[text] at (2,4) {/p/};

\draw (2.5,4) -- (5,5);
\draw (2.5,4) -- (5,3);

\node[text,align=left] at (7.2,5) {\textipa{[b]} / [+voice] \_\_ [+voice]};
\node[text,align=left] at (6.5,3) {[p] / elsewhere};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Are you looking for `anchor=west`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `anchor=west` to specify the location of the box via its leftmost point, or just `right`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (2,4) {/p/};
 \draw (2.5,4) -- (5,5) node[right,align=left] {\textipa{[b]} / [+voice] \_\_ [+voice]};
 \draw (2.5,4) -- (5,3) node[right,align=left] {[p] / elsewhere};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (2,4) {/p/};
 \draw (2.5,4) -- (5,5) node[anchor=west,align=left] {\textipa{[b]} / [+voice] \_\_ [+voice]};
 \draw (2.5,4) -- (5,3) node[anchor=west,align=left] {[p] / elsewhere};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that, besides of marmot's methods. Here are three of them (I will add more if I find one in the future).

#### Method 1

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[right] {Something} -- (-2,-1) node[left] {Dummy text} -- (0,-2) node[right] {Hello World};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use polar coordinates instead of Cartesian coordinates. Also, this way is quite natural (I prefer this way) and doesn't require any Ti*k*Z libraries. However, this is not quite a standard way (`\draw` is not supposed to do this stuff, as far as I know).

#### Method 2

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x) {Something};
\node[below left=1cm and 2cm of x.south west] (o) {Dummy text};
\node[below right=1cm and 2cm of o.south east] (y) {Hello World};
\draw (x.west)--(o.east)--(y.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This way use the standard command for inserting strings to Ti*k*Z pictures: `\node`. However, aligning the texts and controlling the positions are not really easy IMHO. You need `positioning` library.

#### Method 3

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=right: Something] (x);
\coordinate[label=right: Hello World,below=2cm of x] (y);
\coordinate[label=left: Dummy text,below left=1cm and 2cm of x] (o);
\draw (x)--(o)--(y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This way uses `\coordinate` command with `label` option.